# MIPS "fetch address not aligned on word boundary" error on l.s instruction

Tags: mips, mips32

I've read through some Q&As about this error on here, but I still don't understand what it means. I have a code in which I try to calculate *p(n, r)* and I keep getting this error: "line 26: Runtime exception at 0x00400044: fetch address not aligned on word boundary 0x00000006". I don't understand how it's not aligned since to my own knowledge, I haven't manipulated the address.

```
# n and r are assumed to be integers and n > r

.data
    textN: .asciiz "enter n: "
    textR: .asciiz "enter r: "

.text
    main: 
        li $v0, 4
            la $a0, textN
            syscall
            li $v0, 6
            syscall
            move $t0, $v0
        
        li $v0, 4
            la $a0, textR
            syscall
            li $v0, 5
            syscall
            move $t1, $v0
        
            move $a0, $t0
            jal Factorial
            la $t7, ($v0)
            l.s $f0, ($t7)   #line 26
            
            sub $a0, $t0, $t1
            jal Factorial
            la $t7, ($v0)
            l.s $f1, ($t7)
            
            div.s $f12, $f0, $f1
            li $v0, 2
            syscall 
            jr $ra
            
        Factorial:
            beq $a0, 1, Exception
            
            subi $sp, $sp, 8
            sw $t0, ($sp)
            sw $t1, 4($sp)
            
            move $t0, $a0
            move $v0, $a0
            
            Loop:
                subi $t0, $t0, 1
                beq $t0, $zero, Exit
                sub $t1, $a0, $t0
                mul $v0, $v0, $t1
                
            Exit:
                lw $t0, ($sp)
                lw $t1, 4($sp)
                addi $sp, $sp, 8
                jr $ra
                
            Exception:
                addi $v0, $v0, 1
                jr $ra
```

At first, I hadn't included the *la* instruction and line 26 was *l.s $f0, ($v0)*. I assumed that the current update to line 26 and 27 was what was missing, but the error I'm receiving has remained unchanged.

Comment: I haven't looked at the whole thing, but fyi, `la $t7, ($v0)` is kind of silly, using an addressing pseudo instruction to copy a register value to another register: it's the same as simpler `move $t7, $v0` (which is a decent mnemonic for MIPS as something like `add $t7, $v0, $0`).

Comment: @ErikEidt oh, thank you. I assumed `la $t7, ($v0)` loaded the address of $v0 into $t7 so `l.s $f0, ($t7)` could load the value inside $v0 into $f0? I don't know what I'm doing lol

Comment: No, MIPS registers don't have addresses, as they don't exist in RAM. They're part of the CPU itself. You would use `la` for something like `la $t7, textN` to get the address of `textN`, then `lbu $t0,0($t7)` to get the first "e" in "enter n:" into `$t0`.

Comment: syscall #6 reads a floating value into `$f0`, not `$v0`.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're using floating point, but if you really want that you'll have to rethink your register usages and positioning of conversions and possibly your calling conversions.  Do you have a version of this in C that works?

Comment: There are a few things to consider when working with floats mixed with ints.  First, the processor can generally only do arithmetic on like data types, so for add or divide, for example, two ints yield another int, or two floats yield another float.  Thus, when mixing data types, you'll need to decide when to convert from using int computations to float computations (and maybe back as needed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're a bit confused about what parentheses really mean.

```
li $t0,8
move $t1,$t0  ;copy the number 8 from $t0 into $t1.
lw $t2,($t0)  ;load the four bytes at memory address 0x00000008 into $t2
```

Essentially, parentheses around a register are the pointer star `*` in C, and `la $t0, myLabel` is the same as `typename* ptr = &myLabel;`. (I used `li` in the example above because a memory address is a number itself, but that's not usually what you would do if you really were dereferencing a pointer.)

Your function `factorial` is intended to return an `int`, so you don't want to dereference that value. Assembly has no type safety at all, and lets you treat any register as a pointer to memory at any time.

The actual source of your error message, however, has to do with a limitation of the MIPS CPU. Your input value for the factorial function was 3, right? I could tell by the error message. Rather than trying to copy the number 6 to `$f1` (which wouldn't work for other reasons) you were trying to load the 4 bytes at memory address `0x00000006`. This won't work, because MIPS can't use `lw` or `sw` to read/write 32-bit values at memory addresses that aren't *aligned*, i.e. not a multiple of 4. Trying to do so will result in a runtime error. But it's clear that's not what you wanted to do anyway.

Comment: Thank you so much! I get it now, both my question and the fact that I didn't need to struggle with floating point in the first place. But, in the case that I did have to use it, where I have two int values in $a0 and $a1 and want to get the float result of dividing them, how can I do that?

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't learned how to manage floats yet. I do know that the conversion isn't automatic, e.g. storing 2 into RAM with `sw` and loading from that same address with a floating point register won't give you `2.0`. There's a conversion instruction but I can't remember what it is.

Comment: On MIPS, integer to floating point and vice versa are performed in the floating point registers.  Move an integer item either from an integer register or from memory into a floating point register, and its bit pattern won't change (same for reverse direction).  The processor doesn't won't whether the number is/was really an integer or float — on such transfers it is just copying bits. Then apply the appropriate conversion to the floating point register, as in `cvt.s.w $f1, $f2`.

Comment: As implied above, the inverse conversion also happens in the float registers and you can then store to memory or transfer to integer register.  `double` precision floats take two MIPS floating point registers (the registers are only 32-bits wide), an even & odd pair to make 64-bit wide float, so use only even register numbers for `double` — but also if you want to change your code from using float to double, sticking to the even registers will make that somewhat easier.

Comment: The floating point registers are subdivided into categories and calling convention usages, so `$f0` for a return value (single or double) and `$f12` for the first argument...  Some of the registers are call-clobbered and others call-preserved by the calling convention.  And as side note, the floating point registers are not good to hold pointers or addresses in that they cannot be dereferenced as the integer registers can, so addressing computation remain in the integer registers.